Is my proof that if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices and $AB$ is invertible, then $A$ and $B$ are invertible valid?
Theorem: Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of the same size.
If $AB$ is invertible, then $A$ and $B$ must also be invertible.
Proof:
Assume $AB$ is invertible.
If $AB$ is invertible, then it follows that ($E_{k}, ... , E_{2}, E_{1}) AB = I$.
This can be rewritten as $AB = (E_{1}^{-1}, E_{2}^{-1}, ... , E_{k}^{-1})$
If $AB$ can be expressed as the product of elementary matrices, then $A$ and $B$ must also be invertible as all elementary matrices are invertible.

What are $E_1, ... , E_n$?

It’s much simpler than that. Just use the fact that determinant of a matrix is nonzero if and only if it’s invertible.

Other possibility: $AB$ is invertible implies that $A$ is right-invertible and $B$ is left-invertible. Now conclude. This holds in every ring with $1$.

All you have done really is to restate the theorem. I guess you're saying that some of the $E_i^{-1}$ combine to give $A$, and the rest give $B$, but that is not necessarily the case. Hint: You have $(E_k,\dotsc, E_1)AB=I$. Can you find an explicity inverse for $B$ from that?

If $Z$ is the matrix inverse of $AB$, then by definition $Z(AB)=(AB)Z=I$; by associativity, then, $(ZA)B=A(BZ)=I$; and so $ZA$ is a left inverse of $B$ and $BZ$ is a right inverse of $A$.  For square matrices, having a left or right inverse is equivalent to being invertible.

To answer your title question: no, your proof is not valid. You have managed to rewrite $AB$ in a few different ways. But your proof gives no information about $A$ itself nor about $B$ itself, and in particular it does not address the issue of whether $A$ and $B$ are invertible. The assertion in your closing sentence has not been justified.

Hint: If $C$ is the inverse of $AB$, then $ABC = CAB = I$. Try to prove that $BCA = I$ also. What does that imply?

Using the Binet's formula:
$0\ne \det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B) \Longrightarrow \det(A)\ne 0\hspace{3pt} \wedge \hspace{3pt} \det(B)\ne 0$.
$\Longrightarrow$ $A,B$ are both invertible.
